# complex eigenvalues and invariant spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am currently reading Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology*, and the following claim is made without proof:

**Given a linear isomorphism $E: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^k$, with $k>2$ and such that $E$ can be represented by a matrix with real entries, $E$ has a one- or two-dimensional invariant space**.

I understand that the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra implies that $E$ has at least one real or complex eigenvalue; if it is real, then $E$ clearly has a one-dimensional fixed space. If it is complex, however, I don't see how there needs to be a two-dimensional invariant space.

If $E$ has complex eigenvalue $a+bi$, then $a-bi$ must also be an eigenvalue (as $E$ contains real entries). These eigenvalues correspond to eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. I assume that the subspace spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ is the desired invariant space, but can't figure out how to prove it. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I wonder why they have $k>2$; it also works for $k=2$ and $k=1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the space spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ is not the space you are looking for: $v_1$ and $v_2$ have complex entries in fact.
So we assume that $v_2=\bar v_1,$ and consider $w_1=v_1+\bar v_1$ and $w_2=(v_1-\bar v_1)i\in\mathbb R.$
Then we see that $$E(w_1)=aw_1+bi(v_1-\bar v_1)=aw_1+bw_2$$
$$E(w_2)=aw_2-b(v_1+\bar v_1)=-bw_1+aw_2.$$
Thus the space spanned by $w_1$ and $w_2$ is invariant under $E.$
Hope this helps.

Comment: why is $E(w_1)=aw_1+bi(v_1-\overline v_1)$ not $E(w_1)=aw_1+bi(v_1+\overline v_1)?$ $E(w_1)=aw_1+biw_1$ no?

Comment: @Goob In fact $E(w_1) = E(v_1+\overline{v}_1)=(a+bi)(v_1)+(a-bi)(\overline{v}_1)$.  Notice that $w_1$ is not an eigen-vector of $E$.  $v_1$ and $\overline{v}_1$ are instead.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense! I found a different? way to do it? Could you take a look at it because when we my subspace is the same as yours it seems but when we apply the transformation to the vectors my result is different from yours. Wondering if you could explain why that happens. Its on the bottom on this page. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As you indicated the result is easy if there are any real eigenvalues, so I'll focus on the contrary case.

Note that your complex eigenvectors don't live in $\Bbb R^k$ at all, but in $\Bbb C^k$. In order to get back to $\Bbb R^k$, you may view it as a *real* subspace of $\Bbb C^k$ (vectors with all coordinates real) and try to construct from the eigenspaces in$~\Bbb C^k$ an invariant subspace in $\Bbb R^k$. It turns out that the complex span of a single eigenvector intersects the real subspace $\Bbb R^k$ trivially, but the complex span of an eigenvector together with its component-wise complex conjugate, which is an eigenvector for the conjugate eigenvalue, does intersect $\Bbb R^k$ in a real $2$-dimensional subspace, invariant under the real linear operator. In fact the component-wise real and imaginary "parts" of a complex eigenvector $v$ (which van be obtained as linear combination of $v$ and its conjugate) span such an invariant subspace. The answer by @awllower details this approach.

There is another approach that avoids complexifying the vector space to begin with. The minimal polynomial $P$ of the linear operator $E$ has real entries (so does its characteristic polynomial, which could be used in this argument as well, invoking the Cayley-Hamilton theorem). It can therefore be decomposed as product $P=P_1\ldots P_m$ of monic irreducible polynomials over the real numbers, where each factor $P_i$ has degree $1$ or $2$ (due to the FTA). Now by definition of the minimal polynomial $P[E]=0$, which becomes
$$
  P_1[E]\circ P_2[E]\circ\cdots\circ P_m[E]=0.
$$
Clearly at least one of the $P_i[E]$ fails to be injective (in fact they all do). Let $0\neq v\in\ker(P_i[E])$. If $\deg(P_i)=1$ then $P_i=X+c$ for some $c\in\Bbb R$ and $v$ is an eigenvector for$~{-}c$ (the easy case). Otherwise $P_i=X^2+bX+c$ for some $b,c\in\Bbb R$, so $E^2(v)+bE(v)+cv=0$ or equivalently $E^2(v)=-bE(v)-cv$ which shows that the span of $v$ and $E(v)$ is an invariant subspace for $E$.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is another way. A has eigenvalue $\lambda$ and eigenvector $\textbf{v}\in \mathbb{C}^n$. We can say $\lambda = a+bi$ and $v_j=x_j+iy_j \text{ for }j=1,2,...,n\Rightarrow \textbf{v}={\textbf{x}}+i\textbf{y}  \text{ where }\textbf{x,y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ . So now we have: $$(1)\quad A\textbf{v}=\lambda \textbf{v}=\lambda (\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}i)=(a+bi)(\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}i)=(a\textbf{x}-b\textbf{y})+i(b\textbf{x}+a\textbf{y})\\$$
But now you also know that $$(2) \quad A\textbf{v}=A(\textbf{x}+\textbf{y}i)=A\textbf{x}+A\textbf{y}i.\\$$
So I can set (1) and (2) equal:
$$A\textbf{x}+A\textbf{y}i=(a\textbf{x}-b\textbf{y})+i(b\textbf{x}+a\textbf{y})$$
But now we can set the real and imaginary parts equal. We have:
$$A\textbf{x}=(a\textbf{x}-b\textbf{y}) \text{ and } A\textbf{y}=(b\textbf{x}+a\textbf{y}), \text{ where }A\textbf{x}, A\textbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
So the invariant subspace is the plane spanned by $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ and is two dimensional.
Could you help me understand the connection between my x and y and your $w_1$ and $w_2$. I think my $2x=w_1$ and $2y=w_2$ so the span is the same, but then when we multiply by A the stuff is different? How?